# Can be .gitignore file be used only in GitHub Repo?

Tags: github, hosting, gitignore, git-repo

I am creating a React App and my superior would want the app to be hosted anywhere but not on GitHub, so I recommended Hostinger.
My question is:
Can I add a `.gitignore` file in Hostinger, or any other hosting service that is not GitHub?

Comment: the `.gitignore` file is a feature of git, GitHub has nothing to do with it. But it also has very little to do with hosting, so I wonder what you expect it to do for you.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub and Hostinger are not the same services.
GitHub is a git-based code hosting platform for keeping your repository, version control, and collaboration like GitLab and BitBucket.
But Hostinger is not a git platform, provides you web hosting services.

You can add .gitignore file all of your git repos (read documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

If you want to hide your some files during the file transfer process from your computer to Hostinger, then .gitignore is not for your purpose. Because the .gitignore file was created for the git system and its existence is considered by git.

If you make your project a git repository and add a .gitignore file, not only GitHub, but all git platforms such as GitLab, BitBucket, or other private git platforms will already check for it.

Comment: Thanks! So it means that my next job is to convience my superior to embrace GitHub. :))